# $(P_n)$ converges to p if and only if every subsequence of $(P_n)$ converges to p

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

In Rudin textbook, there are lines, "$(P_n)$ converges to p if and only if every subsequence of $(P_n)$ converges to p. We leave the details to the reader."

I'm confused because I thought there can exist several different subsequential limits?

Comment: Sure, in general, a sequence may have different subsequences converging to different limits. In that case, the sequence itself does not converge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, a sequence may have several subsequential limits, but this is assuming $x_n$ already converges, or that every subsequences converges to the same limit, that is

> A sequence converges to $p$ if and only if every subsequence converges to $p$.

One claim is easy, since $x_n$ is a subsequence of itself. The other is slightly more intricate:

Suppose $x_n$ converges. Then for any $\epsilon >0$ we can find $N$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $$|x_n-p|<\epsilon$$

Let $x_{n_k}$ be any subsequence. Pick $K$ such that $k\geq K$ gives $n_k\geq N$. Then when $k\geq K$, $$|x_{n_k}-p|<\epsilon$$

so $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}x_{n_k}=p$ as well.

Answer (score 2):

There can exist many subsequential limits **IF** the sequence $\{P_n\}$ doesn't converge. If it converges (to $X$), for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N$ such that for all $n > N$, $|P_n - X| < \epsilon$, which holds obviously for any subsequence as well. This shows the forward direction; for the converse, note that $\{P_n\}$ is a subsequence of itself.