# Find limit points

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Suppose you have the following complex sequence: 
$\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$

$a_n=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{k}n}$

For $k=1,2,3$ I have to find the limit points and I have to find out if the sequence converges. 
I've been told that the limit points are:

$k=1$ is $2\pi$

$k=2$ is $\pi,2\pi$

$k=3$ is $\frac{2\pi}{3}, \frac{2\pi}{4}, 2\pi$

But I can't seem to graspe why?

As for the convergence, I have concluded that the sequence convergece when $k=1$, but not when $k=2,3$ because then you have more limit points, and therefore the sequence can't convergece to one single point. 
If this a correct assumption? I can't seem to find anything in my book about it, but it seems logic to me, since a sequence can only approach one limit.

Comment: I believe that concept that you are looking for is subsequences and their limits. In particular, a sequence converges (to some finite limit) if and only if every subsequence of it converges to the same limit. A simple google search will yield numerous results on it. You may also refer to: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456082/p-n-converges-to-p-if-and-only-if-every-subsequence-of-p-n-converges-to

Comment: Here's a hint: The sequence is periodic, with period $k$.

Comment: Okay, so when $k=1$ it goes around the whole unit-circle, always going to $2\pi$, but when $k=2$ the unit-circle gets split into 2, hence going to $\pi$ and $2\pi$. Same concept with $k=3$. Am I getting somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In case $k=3$ we have
>   \begin{align*}
> a_{n}=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}n}=
> \begin{cases}
> 1&\qquad n\equiv 0\pmod{3}\\
> e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}=\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}}{2}&\qquad n\equiv 1\pmod{3}\\
> e^{\frac{4\pi i}{3}}=\frac{-1-\sqrt{3}}{2}&\qquad n\equiv 2\pmod{3}\\
> \end{cases}
> \end{align*}
>
> Each of the three values is a limit point and as you correctly reasoned the sequence $\left(a_{n}\right)_{n\geq 0}$ does not converge, since a convergent sequence has to have precisely one limit point $a$.

This point $a$ has the property that  for each $\varepsilon>0$ we find an index $N\in\mathbb{N}$ with
\begin{align*}
|a-a_n|<\varepsilon \qquad\qquad\forall n>N
\end{align*}

> In the first case with $k=1$ the sequence converges since it is  a constant sequence 
>   \begin{align*}
> (a_{n})_{n\geq 0}=\left(e^{2\pi i n}\right)_{n\geq 0}=(1)_{n\geq 0}
> \end{align*}