# A sequence converges iff every subsequence converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

**I know this question has been asked many times on this site. I just wanted to make sure how I wrote this proof out is clear enough.**

> Theorem
>
> $ \{ p_n \} $ converges to $p$ if and only if every subsequence of$ \{ p_n \} $ converges to $p$

Proof. Every sequence is a subsequence of itself so I won't bother with that direction.

For the other, let $ \{ p_n \} $ be a sequence in a metric space $X$ that converges to $p$. By definition this means for every $\epsilon >0$ there is an integer $N$ such that for all $n > N$ implies that $$d(p,p_n) < \epsilon.$$
Let $ \{ p_{n_i} \} $ be a subsequence of $ \{ p_n \} $. Any point  $p_{n_k}$ of    $ \{ p_{n_i} \} $ is also a point of $ \{ p_n \}. $ Hence $  p_{n_k} = p_n$ for some $k$. Therefore,   $$d(p,p_{n_k}) =d(p,p_n) < \epsilon$$  $$d(p,p_{n_k}) <  \epsilon.$$$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

This is in contrast with many solutions that states the position of point  $p_{n_k}$ (in different notation):

[image]

- Link to the [question is here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456082/p-n-converges-to-p-if-and-only-if-every-subsequence-of-p-n-converges-to). Is the way I give the proof "correct enough." If not, can you explain what I miss out on by stating it as such. Thanks a lot all.

Comment: "Hence $p_{n_k}=p_n$ for some $k$" Uptil that point you only spoke of some $N$ corresponding with $\epsilon$. What is $n$ here? It seems to be falling from the sky.

Comment: $n$ would denote the position of the $nth$ point of the sequence as I'm sure you know. I thought it would be clear from stating the definiton of convergence, no??

Comment: "$p_{n_k}=p_n$ for some $k$" This sounds strange. If e.g. $n_k=2k$ then then is there necessarily some $k$ with e.g. $p_{n_k}=p_5$ (that is $p_{2k}=p_5$)? It can be very well that $p_5\notin\{p_2,p_4,p_6,\dots\}$.

Comment: I don't understand how $n_k=2k$ if I'm taking $k$ to be a subscript of $n$ not as multiplication?? If you do mean $n_k = 2k$ then there couldn't be a  $p_{2k}=p_5$ because the value of n is different on both sides of this equation, there could be $p_{2k}=p_2$ or $p_{5k}=p_5$

Comment: I agree with drhab. This part should be "$p_{n_k}=p_j$ for some $j$." The problem afterwards is that you cannot ensure that this particular $j$ is bigger than $N(\epsilon)$. If you start with $\forall k>N$, thus $n_k>N$, then it should work.

Comment: And of course "$p_{n_k}=p_j$ for some $j$" is true, since you can take $j=n_k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is your aim to prove that every subsequence $(p_{n_k})_k$  of a sequence $(p_n)_n$ will converge to $p$ whenever $(p_n)_n$ converges to $p$.

Unfortunately your effort makes no sense.

This is the way to do it:

---

Assume that $(p_n)_n$ converges to $p$ and that $(p_{n_k})_k$ is an arbitrary subsequence of $(p_n)_n$.

Then it is enough to prove that in this situation $(p_{n_k})_k$ converges to $p$.

For this let $\epsilon>0$.

It is enough now to prove that some index $K$ exists with $k>K\implies d(p,p_{n_k})<\epsilon$.

Note that some index $N$ exists with $n>N\implies d(p,p_n)<\epsilon$ because $(p_n)_n$ converges to $p$.

We have $n_1<n_2<n_3<\cdots$ so some $K$ will exist with $n_{K}>N$.

This $K$ does the job, since $k>K\implies n_k>n_{K}>N\implies d(p,p_{n_k})<\epsilon$.

We are ready.

Comment: Thanks! Just one question,why did you choose the notation $(p_{n_k})_k$ instead of $(p_{n_k})$ when stating the theorem before the proof? I mean what is the index k outside for?

Comment: What you call the index outside can be left out. Just $(p_{n_k})$ is okay too. As long as it's clear the we are dealing with sequence $p_{n_1},p_{n_2},\dots$.

Comment: You can exploit the fact that n_k >= k for every k to make this proof a good deal more concise.

Comment: About this, is it true that if any **increasing** seqeuence converges then any **sequence** converges?

Comment: @Nicolò I do not really understand what you mean. It is not true that any increasing sequence converges and something that is false implies everything. So it also implies that any sequence converges. Did you mean any increasing *sub*sequence perhaps?

Comment: @drhab yes sorry, I would say *sub*...

Comment: @Nicolò If a sequence is bounded above then automatically every increasing subsequence will converge. But bounded sequences exist that do not converge.

Comment: @drhab Yes, (I'm thinking about oscillating sequence). But now I have a new doubt. If I have a function $F$ for which I have that $F(x_n)$ converge to $\tilde{F}$ for **any increasing** sequence $\{x_n\}_n$, this implies that $F(x_n)$ converges to $\tilde{F}$ for **any** sequence $\{x_n\}_n$?

Comment: @Nicolò Sorry but actually this is not where comments are for and I have decided not to go any further. If you want an answer on this then you can of course pose it on this site as a question.